# convert sql query (join) in laravel query builder

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, join, controller

I want to do this request with laravel ( i have 3 tables `users` , `userprojet` and `projets` ) `users` hasmany `projets` and `projet` `hasmany` `users` that's why i do another table `userprojet`  to join the two table
and now i try to extract the `projet` of a specific user with this request

```
   select projets.* 
     from projets p 
        , userprojet up 
        , users u 
    where p.id= up.projet_id
      and up.user_id = u.id
      and user_id = 2;
```

I need help please.

Comment: Can you add a reproducible code snippet inside your code-base? This will help others to identify your current solution and give advise and support.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$users = DB::table('projets')
            ->join('userprojet', 'projet_id.id', '=', 'userprojet.projet_id')
            ->join('userprojet', 'users.id', '=', 'userprojet.user_id')
            ->select('project.*')
            ->where('userprojet.user_id', 2)
            ->get();
```

References:

[Laravel -> Queries -> Joins](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#joins)

Comment: i try with your solution , i do this two methods in model ana i return to the project controller i do this:

Comment: $id = auth()->user()->id;
        $user = User::find($id);
        
     return $user->projets();
and i have this error :
Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany could not be converted to string {"userId":3,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Object of class Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Relations\\BelongsToMany could not be converted to string at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\gestion-master\\vendor\\symfony\\http-foundation\\Response.php:404)

Answer (score 0):

You can also define many to many relationship in your models instead of writing queries every time

```
// User model
public function projets()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Projet::class, 'userprojet');
}

// Projet model
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'userprojet');
}

// in controller
$user = User::first(); // for example
dd($user->projets);

// with eager loading
$user = User::with('projets')->first();
dd($user->projets);
```

Comment: i try with your solution , i do this two methods in model ana i return to the project controller i do this:
$id = auth()->user()->id; $user = User::find($id); return $user->projets(); and i have this error : Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany could not be converted to string {"userId":3,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Object of class Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Relations\\BelongsToMany could not be converted to string at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\gestion-master\\vendor\\symfony\\http-foundation\\Response.php:404)

Comment: first you don't need to find user by auth user id, because auth user is already a user instance, and for the error - you get an error because you return query not collection. change `return $user->projets(); ` to `return $user->projets;` as shown in example

Comment: Sorry because i spent many days for send you this but i have another problem when i use $user->projet 
 Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$projets {"userId":3,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined property: Illuminate\\Pagination\\LengthAwarePaginator::$projets at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\gestion\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\API\\ProjetController.php:178)